# VBCSCompiler starts after each request for ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, roslyn

I have two identical asp.net webforms applications deployed on IIS. One is extremely slow and I found out that reason is, that vbcscompiler runs after each request.

Temporary solution was remove this part from the web.config:

```
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
```

But second instance of the app runs pretty fast with this part and compiler doesn't start.
Between deploying of these two instances is few weeks so I don't know now, what was done differently then. All files are identical and the settings on the IIS seems to be the same on first look.

On the server is Kaspersky antivirus. I don't know whether can have some affect to this.

Comment: You can try to disable option "precompile during publish" in VS when deploy application on IIS.

Comment: It looks, that it is solved. We tried to disable antivirus and try enable later again. Everything seems to be OK now.

Thank you for the answer. When again appear this issue I will try this option.

Comment: @Tonick Yes, I can confirm, that the `Kaspersky Security Service` introduces issues with `VBCSCompiler`. As a quick workaround for production: 1) Disable the service 2) Start the web app (compiler kicks in) 3) Start the antivirus service again

Comment: I guess the problem is (at least in our case), that we are using a `DllImport` of the `kernel32.dll`